# Initializing log4j for a stand alone application

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm a newbie to log4j.  This is what I have . I have about 20 files in different packages in a STAND ALONE JAVA APPLICATION. 
I am trying to use and write log files.

Following is my **log4j.properties file** which is in my class path:

```
log4j.appender.R = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File = /ParentFolder/ChildFolder/application.log
log4j.appender.R.Append = true
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
```

**Following is the code to initialize logging** in my main method

```
final String LOG_FILE = "C:/eclipse_workspace/lib/log4j.properties"; 
      Properties logProp = new Properties();      
      try     
      {      
       logProp.load(new FileInputStream (LOG_FILE));  
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(logProperties);      
            logger.info("Logging enabled");    
      }     
      catch(IOException e)                
      {       
     System.out.println("Logging not enabled");       
                 }
```

**In every java class of the application I have the following code**

```
import org.apache.log4j.*;

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TheActualClassName.class);
```

But **I get the following warning messages when I run the app**.

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.xxx.myApp.MainProgram.MyFileName).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

What am I doing wrong?? The log file "application.log" is not being generated

Comment: also, you can use Logger.getRootLogger() without having to write the class as an argument

Comment: You could read the linked document, it tells you everything you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May need the following line:

```
# Set root logger level to INFO and appender to R.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, R
```

The root logger is always available and does not have a name.

Since the version 1.2.7, log4j (with the `LogManager` class) looks for `log4j.xml` in the classpath first. If the `log4j.xml` not exists, then log4j (with the `LogManager` class) looks for `log4j.properties` in the classpath.

- [Default Initialization Procedure](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit)
- [LogManager xref](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/xref/org/apache/log4j/LogManager.html)

Comment: It was just this. Now there are no errors and I also have a log file in the designated folder. Thanks Paul

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use a file named `log4j.properties`, *and* it's on your application's classpath, there is no need to even call `PropertyConfiguration` or `DOMConfigurator` - [log4j will do this automatically](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit) when it is first initialized (when you first load a logger).

The error message seems to indicate that your configuration is not being loaded.

Add the VM argument `-Dlog4j.debug` to your application to have log4j spit out a whole bunch of information when it starts up, which includes which files it tries to load and what values it finds in the configuration.

Comment: using xmlconfigurator would they be of any improvement?

Comment: @Morpheus, no, as the problem would be the same - the configurator is not able to read the configuration being passed to it, likely because of path issues.

Comment: Since version 1.2.7, log4j looks for `log4j.properties` and `log4j.xml` in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Raghu ,if you are using stand alone configuration for configuring log4j Properties then use can use BasicConfigurator.configure() method for solving your appenders issue.